# Problem with Azure Notification Hub and getting registrations

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub, notificationhubclient

Currently using Azure Notification Hub for sending pushnotifications.
When calling the NotificationHub-Client GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync from our API it fails with a TaskCanceledException. This has started to happen after the service has been running for months.
I can see in the Azure service (the hub) that dailyMaxActiceDevices property pretty often gets updated like it's hitting a roof. With the basic subscription for this service we are far from the limit of total registered devices.

Does anyone have a clue of what causes this error? I have not found any similar issues being reported.

Anyway, this is the stacktrace:

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.d__201.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.d__200.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient.d__192`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

The code which the message tells the exception was thrown is as follows:

```
if (handle != null)
{
var registrations = await hub.GetRegistrationsByChannelAsync(handle, 100);

foreach (RegistrationDescription registration in registrations)
{
if (newRegistrationId == null)
{
newRegistrationId = registration.RegistrationId;
}
else
{
await hub.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registration);
}
}
}
```

Have not done any changes to the code yet, because the problem doesn't occur all the time, but it has increased lately.
I have checked the NotificationHub for any reported issues without finding any.